# Entity Framework very slow performance when get the navigation property

Tags: performance, entity-framework, navigation-properties

There are just two simplest table A and B where A contains many B as below table. Then I create 20000 record of B and add them to one A. Now, if I restart the program and execute the if(a.Bs==null) code line as below, it will cost 120 seconds!!

I don't think 20000 records is a big thing to EF, so is there anyone who can help me about this performance issue?

```
public class A
{
    [Key]
    public int EntityId { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<B> Bs { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    [Key]
    public int EntityId { get; set; }
    public virtual A A { get; set; }
}
```

////////////The Context is://///////////////

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext()
        : base("MyDbContext")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<A> As { get; set; }
    public DbSet<B> Bs { get; set; }
}
```

///////////Performance issue as below//////////////

```
using (var db = new MyDbContext())
{
    var a = db.As.First();

    if (a.Bs == null)\\This line will cost about 120 seconds!!!!!!
    {}
}
```

Comment: Probably because you don't have any indexes and calling `a.Bs` is telling EF to get every single B related to A.

Comment: Thanks but actually, the EF will automatically create the IX_A_EntityId in Table B. So, this seems not the reason.

Comment: I took a look at SQL Profiler. Only one sql was execute which is just cost a few millisecond.

Comment: The biggest cost was caused by the creation of the proxyClass. When I write below code line:
db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false; 
It will return at once but a.Bs is null.
So, could anyone help me?

Comment: Can you try to use `if (!a.Bs.Any())` - is that faster?

Comment: Thanks but the issue is still there. If we touch a.Bs, the CPU will up to 25%. I also try to a.Bs.First(), it has the same performance issue. And I try to add another 20000 recored B to the A, the time cost will up to 15 mins. It is a nolinear performance issue.

So, now I have to use db.Bs.Where(x=>x.A==a). This does not has the performance issue. But I think a.Bs will be used by other logic, e.g. the odata query in other business layer. 

But however, I really don't know why a.Bs will cost such many time. Could someone help me to optimize it? Or the best practice for a.Bs?

Answer (score 0):

In your code, when you access a.Bs, all the collection is materialized (by lazy loader) and 20.000 records materialization takes a lot of time. Also, I think that a.Bs is never null.
If you don't need Bs loaded in memory you can find another way to make the check, i.e.

```
if (a.Bs.Count() == 0) {}
```

Comment: Thanks but a.Bs will be null if there is no B in the database.

Comment: And the if (a.Bs.Count() == 0) {} will also cost the same time as a.Bs.Any() or a.Bs.FirstOrDefault() since we try to get a.Bs.